# Search date in array Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have many documents like this one:

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("54a94200aa76d3db6cd51977"), 
    "URL" : "http://...", 
    "Statistics" : [
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2010-05-18T18:07:29.000+0000"), 
            "Clicks" : NumberInt(250), 
        }, 
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2010-05-21T12:06:41.000+0000"), 
            "Clicks" : NumberInt(165), 
        }, 
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2010-05-30T08:37:50.000+0000"), 
            "Clicks" : NumberInt(263), 
        } 
    ]
}
```

My query looks like this:

```
db.clicks.aggregate([
    { $match : 'Statistics.Date' : { $gte: new Date("2010-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: new Date("2010-05-18T23:59:59.999Z") } },
    { $unwind' => '$Statistics' },
    { $group : { _id : { year : { $year : '$Statistics.Date' }, month : { $month : '$Statistics.Date' }, day : { $dayOfMonth : '$Statistics.Date' } }, Clicks : { $sum : '$Statistics.Clicks' } },
    { $sort : { _id : 1 } }
])
```

When I try to sum up the clicks from a specific date it gives me all dates, instead of only one. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**
As there are >80.000 documents in that collection I can't do a `$unwind` before the `$match`. Also afaik this would be not a good idea, 'cause that would make the query slower than necessary.
The huge amount of documents and data in it is the reason why I have to use `$sum`. The document I made above is just an example and only the structure is the same as in my project.

The above query gives me back smth like this:

```
{
    "_id" : [
        { 
        "year" : 2010,
        "month" : 5,
        "day" : 18
        }
    ],
    "Clicks" : 250
},
{
    "_id" : [
        { 
        "year" : 2010,
        "month" : 4,
        "day" : 21
        }
    ],
    "Clicks" : 165
},
{
    "_id" : [
        { 
        "year" : 2010,
        "month" : 5,
        "day" : 30
        }
    ],
    "Clicks" : 263
}
```

If I don't use `$group` I also have to use `$limit` as the query would exceed 16MB otherwise:

```
db.clicks.aggregate([
        { $match : 'Statistics.Date' : { $gte: new Date("2010-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: new Date("2010-05-18T23:59:59.999Z") } },
        { $unwind' : '$Statistics' },
        { $limit : 1 }
    ])
```

This result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("54a94200aa76d3db6cd51977"), 
    "URL" : "http://...", 
    "Statistics" : {
        "Date" : {
            "sec" : 1274166878,
            "usec" : 0
        },
        "Clicks" : 250
    }
}
```

Due to performance reasons I have to use `$group` and not using it is not an option.

As I have all done in PHP there may be some errors in the document, queries and results I mentioned. Hopefully this won't be a problem. I still haven't figured out what's causing my problem. Can anyone help me?

**Edit 2:**
As this seems to be an performance issue which can't be solved I'm migrating all the data from the 'Statistics' array into an own collection. Thx to anyone for your help.

Comment: Hi could you just query for the the item which matches that date and see what result is coming

Comment: try first `unwind` and then `match` may solve your problem or add  same `match` after `unwind`  in your existing query

Comment: Actually @yogesh is right you have to unwind the data first then match because without unwinding it will match the whole staticstics row

Comment: I can't do an `$unwind` before due to performance reasons. There are more than 80.000 documents like that one I mentioned inside the collection. Most of the time it just ends up in an error like "There was no answer until 30 seconds".
When I do a `$limit` for just one item, it also gives me all the dates. That behaviour stops, when I don't put the `$group` stuff inside the query.

Comment: maybe you should add `allowDiskUse` [check here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate) in your aggreagtion

Comment: Did that and still I get "MongoCursorTimeoutException". I had performance issues with `$unwind` before and everyone told me to do `$match` before `$unwind`. Even when there are array fields in it. Which was working perfect. As the data is for a graph it's not acceptable to let the users wait for a long time.
Seems like a problem with `$group`. If I don't put it inside the query, it gives me all documents in which the Statistics.Date field matches the date inside the query. Showing just that one Statistics object with that date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your `$match` twice, both before *and* after the `$unwind`:

```js
db.clicks.aggregate([
    { $match : { 'Statistics.Date' : { 
        $gte: new ISODate("2010-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"), 
        $lte: new ISODate("2010-05-18T23:59:59.999Z") } } },
    { $unwind: '$Statistics' },
    { $match : { 'Statistics.Date' : {
        $gte: new ISODate("2010-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"), 
        $lte: new ISODate("2010-05-18T23:59:59.999Z") } } },
    { $group : { 
        _id : { year : { $year : '$Statistics.Date' }, 
                month : { $month : '$Statistics.Date' }, 
                day : { $dayOfMonth : '$Statistics.Date' } },
        Clicks : { $sum : '$Statistics.Clicks' } } },
    { $sort : { _id : 1 } }
])
```

The first `$match` is used to select the documents with at least one `Statistics` element in the right date range.  The second one is used to filter out the other `Statistics` elements of those docs that aren't in the right date range.

Comment: Ok, I had not mentioned this, but I also already tried that. This ends up in a "MongoCursorTimeoutException". Even when `$limit` is set to 1.

Comment: Have you tried using a longer cursor timeout?  http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php

Comment: No, 'cause it has to be fast as the data will be used for a graph. No user wants to wait for the requested data longer than 1 Minute I guess.

Comment: Then you'll need to add an index on `Statistics.Date` if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: To improve performance further, you'd likely have to change your schema to move your data out of the `Statistics` arrays and into a separate collection. But that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Yes, we're just migrating all the data from the `Statistics` array into a new collection since yesterday before I've seen your answer. We had this in mind since I was asking my question in here. Nevertheless I think this is going more into the direction of a SQL based database. That's why we tried so long to get the data out of an array of the object/document were it belongs to. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Things may have been solved but posting answer for ones who are seeking help from this question

```
{ $match : 'Statistics.Date' : { $gte: new Date("2010-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"), 
enter code here$lte: new Date("2010-05-18T23:59:59.999Z") } }
```

this match will filter main documents. What you want is to filter the documents inside Statistics array.
Now documents filtered by `$match` will contain full Statistic array. And unwinding after filtering may have Sub-document of Statistic whose sibling document(document that are in the same array) have passed `$match` condition.

> Note: simple find projection:
>   `db.col_name.find({},{"Statistics.$":1})` will filter array too but
>   `$project` in aggregation is not helping in filtering array of documents.